# Ошибка при использовании npm i, зависимости не скачиваются

Tags: javascript, html, css, консоль, npm

Каждый раз когда я в консоль ввожу npm i он выдает кучу ошибок

```
npm i
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN deprecated @stylelint/postcss-markdown@0.36.2: Use the original unforked package instead: postcss-markdown
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated xmldom@0.1.27: Deprecated due to CVE-2021-21366 resolved in 0.5.0
npm WARN deprecated phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16: this package is now deprecated
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\goodc\Desktop\l\my-main-gulp\My gulp maxgraph\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\goodc\Desktop\l\my-main-gulp\My gulp maxgraph\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\goodc\\Desktop\\l\\my-main-gulp\\My gulp maxgraph\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\goodc\Desktop\l\my-main-gulp\My gulp maxgraph\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\goodc\Desktop\l\my-main-gulp\My gulp maxgraph\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\goodc\Desktop\l\my-main-gulp\My gulp maxgraph\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\goodc\Desktop\l\my-main-gulp\My gulp maxgraph\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\goodc\Desktop\l\my-main-gulp\My gulp maxgraph\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\goodc\Desktop\l\my-main-gulp\My gulp maxgraph\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\goodc\Desktop\l\my-main-gulp\My gulp maxgraph\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\goodc\Desktop\l\my-main-gulp\My gulp maxgraph\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\goodc\Desktop\l\my-main-gulp\My gulp maxgraph\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\goodc\Desktop\l\my-main-gulp\My gulp maxgraph\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\goodc\Desktop\l\my-main-gulp\My gulp maxgraph\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\goodc\Desktop\l\my-main-gulp\My gulp maxgraph\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python39\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\goodc\\Desktop\\l\\my-main-gulp\\My gulp maxgraph\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\goodc\Desktop\l\my-main-gulp\My gulp maxgraph\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\goodc\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-02T14_45_15_329Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: последовать предлагаемым в приложенном вами тексте советам что-то мешает? изложите, пожалуйста, эти причины прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

У вас прямо в тексте ошибки написано

```
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
```

Что свидетельствует о том, что у вас не установлен Python (либо он установлен но его нету в переменной PATH), либо просто поменяйте версию ноды на более старую.